# Metal fragment shader - How do I assign each pixel a color based on the uniforms that I can adjust via the draw function?

Tags: ios, metal, fragment-shader

I have a MTKView that is rendering a cube that is sized so that one of its faces fills the entire screen.

I am passing a struct variable (called theuniforms) that contains a random Float to the fragment shader and I want to color each pixel on the screen a different color depending on the float's value.

Right now, it is coloring the entire quad red or blue depending on the Float's value, which is randomized in the draw function.

I think my setup is wrong because at any frame I will only have access to one random Float, and all of the pixels will be colored during that frame (I won't have an array of random floats to determine the pixel color).  However, I think I could simply add more variables to the struct variable to overcome this problem.

The main issue is accessing the individual pixel via the fragment function... and if it will be even performant enough to determine a color for every pixel on the screen.

```
import UIKit
import MetalKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MTKViewDelegate {
     
     var metaldevice: MTLDevice!
     var metalview: MTKView!
     var metallibrary: MTLLibrary!
     var metalqueue: MTLCommandQueue!
     var metalpipelinestate: MTLRenderPipelineState!
     var metalmesh: MTKMesh!
     
     var theuniforms = Uniforms(color: 1)
     
     struct Uniforms {
          var color = Float(1)
     }
     
     override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }
     override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool { return true }
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          self.view.backgroundColor = .black
          
          self.metaldevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
          self.metalview = MTKView()
          self.metalview.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
          self.metalview.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
          self.metalview.delegate = self
          self.metalview.device = self.metaldevice
          self.view.addSubview(self.metalview)
          
          self.metallibrary = self.metaldevice.makeDefaultLibrary()
          self.metalqueue = self.metaldevice.makeCommandQueue()
          self.metalmesh = self.returncube()
          
          let vfunc = self.metallibrary.makeFunction(name: "vertex_main")
          let ffunc = self.metallibrary.makeFunction(name: "fragment_main")
          let descriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
          descriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
          descriptor.vertexFunction = vfunc
          descriptor.fragmentFunction = ffunc
          descriptor.vertexDescriptor = MTKMetalVertexDescriptorFromModelIO(self.metalmesh.vertexDescriptor)
          
          self.metalpipelinestate = try! self.metaldevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: descriptor)
          

     }


     func returncube() -> MTKMesh {
          let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: self.metaldevice)
          let model = MDLMesh(boxWithExtent: [2, 2, 2], segments: [1, 1, 1], inwardNormals: false, geometryType: .triangles, allocator: allocator)
          let mesh = try! MTKMesh(mesh: model, device: self.metaldevice)
          return mesh
     }
     
     func draw(in view: MTKView) {
          let descriptor = self.metalview.currentRenderPassDescriptor
          let buffer = self.metalqueue.makeCommandBuffer()
          let encoder = buffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor!)
          encoder?.setRenderPipelineState(self.metalpipelinestate)
          
          self.theuniforms.color = Float.random(in: 1.0...2.0)
          
          encoder?.setVertexBytes(&theuniforms, length: MemoryLayout<Uniforms>.stride, index: 1)
          encoder?.setVertexBuffer(self.metalmesh.vertexBuffers[0].buffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
          for mesh in self.metalmesh.submeshes {
               encoder?.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangle, indexCount: mesh.indexCount, indexType: mesh.indexType, indexBuffer: mesh.indexBuffer.buffer, indexBufferOffset: mesh.indexBuffer.offset)
          }
          
          encoder?.endEncoding()
          let drawable = self.metalview.currentDrawable
          buffer?.present(drawable!)
          buffer?.commit()
          
     }
     
     func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
          
     }
}
```

here is the shader code

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <simd/simd.h>

struct VertexIn {
     float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
};

struct Uniforms {
     float color;
};

struct VertexOut {
     float4 position [[position]];
     Uniforms uniforms;
};

vertex VertexOut vertex_main(const VertexIn in [[stage_in]],
                          constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]]
                          )
{
     VertexOut out;
     out.position = in.position;
     out.uniforms = uniforms;
     return out;
}

fragment float4 fragment_main( VertexOut in [[stage_in]])
{
     
     float4 color;
     
     if (in.uniforms.color > 1.5){ color = float4(1, 0, 0, 1); }
     else { color = float4(0, 0, 1, 1); }
     return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't use uniforms to change the color of each pixel you overload the CPU but this is a GPU task so you should use some function inside the shader. And if you want uniforms to change the color of fragment accordingly you must pass it into the fragment function `setFragmentBytes(&theuniforms, length: MemoryLayout<Uniforms>.stride, index: 1)` and call it in the fragment function. If I get you right you want something like white noise on the cube so here is the shader:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <simd/simd.h>

struct VertexIn {
     float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
};

struct Uniforms {
     float color;
};

struct VertexOut {
     float4 position [[position]];
};

vertex VertexOut vertex_main(const VertexIn in [[stage_in]])
{
     VertexOut out;
     out.position = in.position;
   
     return out;
}



float rand(float2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,float2(12.9898,78.236))) * 43758.5453);
}


fragment float4 fragment_main( VertexOut in [[stage_in]],constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]])
{
              
                                                                                      
     float2 pos = in.position.xy;
     
     float4 color = float4(rand(pos));
     
     //if (in.uniforms.color > 1.5){ color = float4(1, 0, 0, 1); }
     //else { color = float4(0, 0, 1, 1); }
     return color;
}
```